# When morphism of complexes is homotopic to 0?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, derived-categories

Let $f\colon A^\bullet\to I^\bullet$ be a morphism of bounded below complexes in an abelian category. Assume all $I^i$ are injective objects. Assume also that $f$ induces the zero map on cohomology.

**Is it true that $f$ is homotopic to 0?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Take a diagram$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0@>{}>>0 @>{}>> I^{1}@>{}>>0 @>{}>>\cdots\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV^{\!\!\!\operatorname{Id}}@VVV \\
0@>{}>>I^0 @>{d}>> I^1@>{}>>0@>{}>>\cdots
\end{CD}$$with $I^0,I^1$ injective and  $d$ a surjective homomorphism which doesn't split. Then $H^0(A^{\bullet})=H^1(I^{\bullet})=0$, so $H^{\bullet}(f)=0$, but $f$ homotopic to $0$ would mean that $d$ splits.